# How to solve Unexpected Exception: TypeError: x is undefined. in Selenium IDE 2.4.0?

Tags: javascript, selenium, ide, undefined

I am new to selenium.
I am trying to test this function to click on a random link in a wepage. I added it as a js user extension.

```
Selenium.prototype.doClickRanLink = function() {


var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var randNum = Math.random(0,4);
links[randNum].click();


};
```

loads fine, and the ClickRanLink shows up in the commands box, but when i run it the error below shows up and I am not sure why as "links" is defined.

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: TypeError: links is undefined.
```

The # of the line of the error corresponds to 
    links[randNum].click();

Any ideas why it does show that error and how to fix it?

Thanks
pdta: using Selenium IDE 2.4.0 + firefox

Answer (score 0):

[Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) does not take any arguments so your `randNum`  is some decimal number between 0 and 1

so this line

```
links[randNum].click();
```

is basically like

```
links[0.815484994].click();
```

and since there is no index 0.815484994 you get an undefined error.

to get a random number using a min max use the following:

```
function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.round( Math.random() * (max - min) + min );
}
```

and use like

```
var randIndex = rand(0,links.length-1);
links[randIndex].click();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I still have the same problem. [error] Unexpected Exception: TypeError: links[1] is undefined.

Comment: do a `console.log(links);` right after your getElementsByTagName call see if it is returning an array of elements, if it is not then it has not found any elements

Comment: Hi, It doesn't return an array. But there are links in the page. And confirmed the path and it's the right one. What could be wrong?

Comment: I checked out his answer, problem is it's still returning a decimal.  Try this instead: `Math.floor(Math.random()*(100-0) + 0)`

Comment: It's not the problem as console.log(links) is invoked before math.floor.

Comment: @richard. forget my last comment. I don't think it's the decimal problem. I deleted the links[randIndex].click() line to check(Thus avoiding the decimal error), and still console.log(links) doesn't show anything.

Comment: How are you invoking your function?  Are you using JavascriptExecutor?

Comment: Yea i forgot to add the Math.round to the min,max random function. @user1338101, the only thing i can think of that would cause `links` to not get the array of anchor tags would be if your `doClickRanLink` is being executed before the DOM is ready

Comment: I am calling the function by selecting ClickRanLink in the command's box of the selenium IDE.

Comment: @patrick: do u mean let give it more time to load? the page is already open. i also tried using 2 other fuctions as user extensions to click random links, same error. there must be some conf. problem, somewhere?